# Slow query with large dataset in Drupal views — better to process in SQL or PHP?

Tags: 7, views, performance

I have a large userbase in my Drupal 7 site, which contains a People finder. Because there are hundreds of thousands of users and we want to display the People finder in a random order on page load, I presume it's transferring the whole userbase into memory at some point, in order to paginate (using the Pager built-in to <s>Views2</s> Views3).

I've noticed that the query has no `limit` against it (presumably because of pagination) and that it `join`s against `users_roles` twice (because I need to include all users of rôle A but not also of rôles B, C and D). I've added comments against the `WHERE` clause to explain each line's purpose and how it's come out of my View.

```sql
SELECT
    users.uid AS uid,
    'user' AS field_data_field_user_image_user_entity_type,
    'user' AS field_data_field_user_field1_user_entity_type,         -- custom field
    'user' AS field_data_field_user_field2_display_user_entity_type, -- custom field
    'user' AS field_data_field_user_field3_user_entity_type,         -- custom field
    'user' AS field_data_field_user_field4_user_entity_type,         -- custom field
    RAND() AS random_field
FROM
    users users
    INNER JOIN users_roles users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
    LEFT JOIN users_roles users_roles2
        ON users.uid = users_roles2.uid
        AND (users_roles2.rid = :views_join_condition_0
          OR users_roles2.rid = :views_join_condition_1
          OR users_roles2.rid = :views_join_condition_2)
WHERE
    (( (users.status <> :db_condition_placeholder_3)      -- Active users only
    AND (users_roles.rid = :db_condition_placeholder_4)   -- Must be in rôle A
    AND (users_roles2.rid IS NULL)                        -- Must not be in rôles B, C, D
    AND (users.uid != :users_uid OR users.uid IS NULL) )) -- Must not be current user
ORDER BY random_field ASC
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there some way in Views2 that I can somehow get this query to be `limit`ed (potentially by sorting on something else that pretends to be random)? I assume that transferring fewer result rows per query is likely to help with the memory overhead?
2. If I want to mess with that `WHERE` clause, am I better off using a PHP Filter Criterion to do the roles messing (which would presumably remove the double-join) or should I move the whole damn query into either a [custom module](http://drupal.org/node/409808)<sup>[a]</sup> or a [mySQL view](http://drupal.org/node/409808#comment-2560626)<sup>[b]</sup>?

<sup>a: I assume that would attach to the relevant hook with a `function modulename_views_pre_execute(&$view)`.

b: I assume a mySQL view would still need to do both `join`s, one `inner join` and one `left join`, so I can't quite see how this would help.</sup>

For what it's worth, I know that my site will have a relatively short lifetime and, during that, the rôles won't change, so I am happy to hardcode the rôle IDs, if that will give me a performance benefit.

Comment: I realise I could also avoid the `join`ing by doing something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid = 5) AND uid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid IN (6,8,9))`. But that's still going to pull back all the rows; would that be better than the double-join?

Comment: Are you using Views 2 or Views 3?  I didn't think that Views 2 ever had a version for Drupal 7.

Comment: @MPD You're right, it's Views3; I thought it was Views2. My bad.

Comment: Just a thought: Do you use indexes on the joined ids and the fileds in the where clause? Using indexes in the right way can speed up your queries dramatically.

Comment: @BetaRide Yes, the `JOIN`ed IDs are both indexed (indeed there are only two columns in `users_roles` and they are a clustered primary key together). I'll double-check `users.status` but I'm pretty sure it's the ugly join that's the problem here.

Comment: I have also opened a question on DBA.SE with the mySQL specific part of this question: [mySQL query optimisation — multiple joins or select … where not in (select distinct…)?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15794/7755)

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% positive that the view isn't paging in SQL?  When you turn on Query Logging in the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, what do you see for your view?  I just double checked a site and am seeing (formatting is mine):

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, RAND() AS random_field
FROM node node
WHERE (( (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
  AND (node.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) ))
ORDER BY random_field ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

when I am on paged view with a random sort.

I have seen the double `JOIN` thing before.  Often, you can adjust the view parameters and get the query to run the way you want.

Optimizing these queries is really use dependent.  I am pretty sure that both of the columns you are joining on are both indexed already.  You can try to replicate the query manually, and then [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) it, and manually improve it.  You can then implement this query in a custom block, but then you lose out on other things that Views give you.  Caching the view results, may help, too.

Keeping everything in MySQL is likely best (it is meant for heavy lifting like this), but only profiling will give the true results for your system.  Just make sure you have MySQL, Apache, and PHP tuned so that you aren't chasing the wrong problem.

Comment: We've been looking at the site performance for a couple of days and it's definitely this query (and one other) on this page that are our main problem. The query in the question is copy/pasted from the output of Devel and then reformatted for legibility. I did look at `EXPLAIN`, but part of my problem is that I can't see how to improve it dramatically from the status quo — I've also [listed the mySQL bit on DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15794/7755) and the subquery option looks slightly better, but I don't quite follow how to use the output of `EXPLAIN`, tbh.

Comment: I just find it very odd that the ORDER/LIMIT is missing from yours, but I see it when I use "Global: Random" as a views sort.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that `ORDER`/`LIMIT` would help here dramatically. But I can't see how to enable them. Is there something I need to do to the Query settings, perhaps? (I have all three checkboxes unticked, so SQL rewriting is _not_ disabled)

Comment: No clue.  Another module may be rewriting the query.  I would try remaking the view w/ a new name and see what happens.  Other than that, you can take @Countzero's advice and try to alter the query.

Comment: Remaking the View with a new name doesn't make any difference, it would seem. It takes pretty much the same time to run each query and there's still no `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` appearing in the SQL query being shown me by [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily modify the query in [hook_views_query_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7), add your `LIMIT` clause and see what you get.

But MPD advice above is very sound and is widely applicable.